# Consider all linear systems with exactly one eigenvalue equal to 0. Which of these systems are conjugate?

Tags: matrices

This question considers non-hyperbolic matrices (2x2), which is not covered in our textbook.  Basically the problem I think tries to get us to think about conjugacy patterns of these cases, but I am stuck.

If A= ((a, b), (c, d)) a 2x2 has 1 eigenvalue = 0, then I believe c or b must be 0.

So A = ((a, 0), (c, d)) or ((a, b), (0, d)), but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Why did you believe this? Counterexample $$  \boldsymbol A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1 \end{bmatrix}. $$

Comment: Ah yes, sorry.  Shows my inexperience with linear algebra!

Answer (score 1):

This means that the matrix has rank 1 or one row is a multiple of another row and one row is non zero. Formally$$k_1(a,b)+k_2(c,d)=0$$and $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\ne 0$$